# Wondering why my code demands a wait timer, since everything should run serial, major nonsensical change without it

Tags: c#

My goal is to create 100 dots and have them take random paths, it's for a simple evolution algorythem. However, it needs a wait timer to make the pathing unique to each dot, and from my testing and viewing of the code I see no reason for that to happen. I could just leave it like it is, but I like to understand the code I write. Because there isn't any specific error or anything, I unfortunately do have to give quite a bit of code (around 200 lines with spaces and comments), I hate doing it, but it really is only the necessary files.
They should be commented pretty well, so I hope that helps at least, sorry for the inconvinience

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;

 class Genetics
{
    //Just a bunch of references to classes
    //----------------------------------------
    Dot.Class dot = new Dot.Class();
    FormSetup setup = new FormSetup();
    Brain.Class brain = new Brain.Class();
    Watch watch = new Watch();
    Population.Class Pop = new Population.Class();
    Dot.Class[] Dots;
    //----------------------------------------
    //The main function just starts a timer, and sets up the form in FormSetup and runs the application


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Genetics gen = new Genetics();
        gen.watch.watch();
        FormSetup.Start();

    }



    //Makes the dots before anything visual occurs
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dots = Pop.Birth();
    }

    //Paint sets up the goal and draws and redraws the dots by following their location
    //This does not fire before the birthing process is done
   public void Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        Goal.Class goal = new Goal.Class();
        Graphics G = e.Graphics;

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        //------------------------------------
        //Goal
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, goal.MakeGoal());

        //Since this should fire as many times as tick, which fires every 50th milisecond, it should follow the dots and drawing spheres from their locations pretty alright
        //Goes through the list from the birth process (Dots) and initiates the Move() method for each of them, which sets their path coordinates randomly. 
        // This path SHOULD be unique to every single on of them, but without a wait timer, they aren't.
        for (int i = 0; i < Dots.Length; i++)
        {
            Dots[i].Move();
            G.DrawEllipse(pen, Dots[i].Location.X, Dots[i].Location.Y, 10, 10);

            // With that testing loop, I saw how that without the sleep function, every dot had the same path, however with it, each dot's path is unique.
           /* for (int b = 0; b < Dots[i].Directions.Length; b++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am dot number: " + i + " And for step number: " + b + " my coordinate is: " + Dots[i].Directions[b]);
            } */
        }






    }
    //This just asks the form to be redrawn every 50th milisecond. This event does not fire before the Birthing process is complete.
    public void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FormSetup.form1.Invalidate();
        FormSetup.form1.Update();
    }


}
```

The code above is the main code, the most likely cause for the problem is the for loop in the paint method

Below is the brain code, which is even weirder for me, more is explained in the comments, but it shouldn't really be impacted by the wait timer at all, but alas, it is.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;

namespace Brain
{

    //The Brain program makes a big array of directions, and then randomizes a whole path of them
   public class Class
    {
        // Sets up the variables
        Point[] Directions;
        Random rand = new Random();

        //The GetDirections methods sets the size of the point array, then runs the randomize method, then returns the directions
        public Point[] GetDirections(int size)
        {

            Directions = new Point[size];
            Randomize();
            return Directions;
        }

        // Simply fills the entire Directions point array with randonmized points
//This will output the same path over and over without the sleep function, however that doesn't make too much sense for me, since this is only called a bit AFTER the sleep function, since this method is only called after load, which stores all the dots
        void Randomize()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Directions.Length; i++)
            {

                Directions[i] = new Point(rand.Next(-5, 5), rand.Next(-5, 5));


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then there is the population code which creates a lot of dots, this is the code that actually births the collection of dots, and also contains the sleep function

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;

namespace Population
{
    public class Class
    {
        //Makes a variable for the dots array
        Dot.Class[] dots;

        //Birth is only called once just before the form is loaded
        public Dot.Class[] Birth()
        {
            //Sets the size of the dots array
            dots = new Dot.Class[100];

            //Fills out the dots array with unique Dot classes
            for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length; i++)
            {

                dots[i] = new Dot.Class();

                //This little thing that the code requires for it to semi-work, and I have no idea why...
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);


            }

            return dots;
        }

    }
}
```

So, as you have probarbly noticed by now, the point was for each dot to have a unique coordinate path, but for some reason it won't do this without a sleep function between each iterration of the for loop, doesn't do anything if it is outside of it.
I am seriously lost here, since I have no idea what my code is doing here, while I am new to forms, it doesn't seem to be a forms problem, since it's the pure coordinates that are the issue, not how they appear on the screen.

I would be very thankful to anyone who wants to even try and help.

Added the Dot code:

```
   public class Class
    {
        //Creates relevant variables for the dots
        public Point Location = new Point(1370/2, 650/2);
        Point Velocity = new Point(0, 0);
        Point accelleration = new Point(0, 0);
        bool IsDead = false;
        int DistanceToGoal = 0;
        public Point[] Directions;

        //Some more variables, these are just used for some cheap programming tricks
        bool StartupComplete = false;
        int steps = 0;

        //Class references
        public Brain.Class brain = new Brain.Class();
        Goal.Class goal = new Goal.Class();


        //This is called every 50th milisecond after the load of the form. Before this Method is called, the dot won't have any coordinates
        public void Move()
        {
            //A one-off if statement that fills the Directions array with the randomized points from the brain
            if (!StartupComplete)
            {
                Directions = brain.GetDirections(500);
                StartupComplete = true;

            }
            //Will only move if not marked as death
            if (!IsDead)
            {
                //Makes sure that we aren't going further into the array than allowed to. We do not use a for loop here, because it is called every 50th milisecond
                if (steps < Directions.Length)
                {
                    //Just fills the accelleration variable with the randomized directions relevant to the current step, and then goes to the next step for the next itteration
                    accelleration.X = Directions[steps].X;
                    accelleration.Y = Directions[steps].Y;
                    steps++;

                }
                //If there are no more directions, the dot is marked as death
                else
                {
                    IsDead = true;
                }
                //Sets and limits the velocity
                    Velocity.Y += accelleration.Y;
                    if (Velocity.Y > 10)
                        Velocity.Y = 10;
                    if (Velocity.Y < -10)
                        Velocity.Y = -10;
                    Velocity.X += accelleration.X;
                    if (Velocity.X > 10)
                        Velocity.X = 10;
                    if (Velocity.X < -10)
                        Velocity.X = -10;

                    //Moves an amount equal to the velocity, then checks if the dot is out of bounds
                    Location.X += Velocity.X;
                    Location.Y += Velocity.Y;
                    CheckDead();


            }
        }
        //Just checks if the dot is just about halfway outside the form size
        void CheckDead()
        {

            if (Location.X > 1374 || Location.X < -0.4)
                IsDead = true;

            if (Location.Y > 654 || Location.Y < -0.4)
                IsDead = true;




        }
```

Comment: It seems like the only thing that could be contributing to the weirdness in your for loop is the creation of the Dot class. I'm guessing there is something "random" being assigned inside of the Dot class, and a lot of pseudo random algorithms depend on the system clock, and that may be why the 50ms sleep is allowing it to work somewhat because without the sleep, the system clock may be too similar between loops?

Comment: @TJRockefeller Gave a bit of a more in-depth comment underneath Pavel's answer, but just wanted to note that there isn't any randomization in the dot code, at least nothing that gets called until after population has done its task, and wouldn't make sense for a code that hasn't been called, to note the time of its referencing, and not of its calling

Comment: Are you creating an instance of `Random` when the Dot class is created? When you instantiate Random without a seed, I'm pretty sure it is using the system clock as your seed, and if you instantiate a bunch of Randoms with essentially the same seed, then it doesn't matter when `Next()` is called, it will return the same value for every Random that was instantiated with the same seed.

Comment: @TJRockefeller

Added the Dot code so you can see it, but no, the only random that is created is in the brain code, the second block of code.
Oh but wait, I do create a brain instance, and the random rand = new random is in the class, not a method, so I might just be indirectly, depends on how the calling of classes functions.

Comment: Yes, but you are creating the Brain class when you create the Dot class, so the `Random` class is initialized in the Brain class when your create your Dot class, and basically all of your Brain classes are creating a `Random` class with the same seed, so they will all return the same values when `Next()` is called.

Comment: @TJRockefeller Ah that makes a whole lot of sense, yeah that does very much seem to be the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess, but it looks like an issue with `Random()` since it's using the clock to generate random numbers. Also it may explain why `Thread.Sleep(50)` helps you with random paths.

Basically, in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. I bet that's what happens here. You should keep a single `Random` instance and keep using `Next` on the same instance.

Try to change your randomizer to use a code below:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random(); 
private static readonly object syncLock = new object(); 
public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    lock(syncLock) { // synchronize
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I made a dot net fiddle that demonstrates how you can end up with the same value if you are creating new `Random`s in a tight loop. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kkbxO3

Comment: I think this totally makes sense, and @TJRockefeller very much proved that randoms in too quick succession can lead to samey result, but from some lovely time watch testing, it really doesn't seem to be the problem here.

The problem with thinking it's the time between randoms that's the problem, is that the Thread.Sleep(50) function isn't anywhere near the randoms. 
The Thread.Sleep(50) function is in population, which is called when the form loads, but the randomization happens right before the dots are drawn in the main/genetic code paint event.

Comment: @MortisFillius What is important here is when `var rand = new Random()` is called, not when `rand.Next()` is called.